# How to implement Horizontal scatter bar graph plot in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am using CorePlot to implement graph. I have implemented Bar Graph but to implement Scatter bar graph, I am facing problem. How to draw Bar of specific length.

[image: I am using CorePlot to implement graph. I have implemented Bar Graph but to implement Scatter bar graph, I am facing problem. How to draw Bar of specific length.]